# Add multiple values to the postgresql using nodeJS Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any possible way to add multiple values to the column?
Right now i have a comments column and I have this code .

```
app.put('/addComment/:id', (req, res) => {

Posts.update({
        comment: req.body.comment
    },
    {
        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        }
    }).then((post) => {
    res.send(post)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("err", err);
});
})
```

But instead of adding another value it just updates old one with new , any suggestions on method which will solve my issue?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple values? Is your column a text? Do you wish to concatenate an existing text in the column with a new one?

Comment: if you want to add another value why your using update method? update method used to change the value of existing.

Comment: the column data_type is text[],I know i should not use update but I'm new to sequelize and I could not find any other method which would suit my proble

Comment: Could you suggest me method which would solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use concat function `sequelize`

It will append new value into the column.

```
const {fn, col } = models.sequelize

Posts.update({
 members: fn('CONCAT', col("comment"), req.body.comment)
}, {
 where: {
  id: req.params.id
 }
}).then(function() {
 console.log("Value Appended");
});
```

Comment: import `Sequelize`

Comment: Ya! it is saved in a single column but is it possible to display it separately in a card view?